# Ontology OWL API java

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege, owl-api

I am taking this Data Based Knowledge class, and I am trying to figure it out how to install first OWL API. First, I create a .owl file in Protege. My teacher told us we have to write a small Java program that reads our .owl file. He told us to include the OWL API; he did not give any instructions and any lectures about OWL API. Do you know how I can install the OWL API is very confusing? And if there is any good tutorial out there that explains how to implement an .owl file into a Java program?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

An .owl file is simply a text file, usually XML.

The OWL API is a library, so you do not need to install it, but simply download it and put it in the classpath for your Java class (I assume you're familiar with Java).

It can be downloaded here: 
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sourceforge.owlapi%7Cowlapi-osgidistribution%7C4.0.0%7Cbundle

There is documentation and tutorials here:

https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation

Support is available on GitHub (simply raise an issue here: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues ) and on the OWLAPI mailing list (details on the documentation page).

Comment: XML is only one of the various syntax, maybe he then want to display axiom of the owl in another syntax to see the 'loading' of the file.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said usually.

Comment: I have read the example very useful and I have implemented the OWL API jar file but the only problem is the reasoner. What is a reasoner? I worked with protege and so far I have individuals objects classes. Also what is an axiom

Comment: A reasoner is a program that answers queries, such as "subclasses of C", through inferences on an ontology. A list of them is here: http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~sattler/reasoners.html and a description of the concept here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_reasoner

Comment: An axiom is simply a small portion of an ontology: if in your ontology two classes are related, and one is contained in another, you will express this as "A subClassIf B". This is a subclass axiom. If the course that you're following does not explain these concepts, and does not provide references for these concepts, these are good questions to ask the teacher.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven then use the following dependency in pom.xml and run mvn install to get all the libraries.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Before diving into creating an owl file yourself, try using existing owl files to understand the format and owlapi itself. For e.g.
http://www.workingontologist.org/Examples/Chapter3/shakespeare.owl or https://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl OWLAPI does not have good documentation on latest releases so one has to dig into the javadocs to see if the interfaces match their requirements.

Tutorials give you some insight on the way things are done. http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/owled2011_tutorial.pdf &
http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/SKB-SemTech-OWLAPI-6up.pdf